# Installing SSH on local windows machine for AWS configuration

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line-interface

I am configuring my AWS CLI and I am trying to setup SSH. Whenever type in anything (I am just trying the default "aws-eb" I always get the error "To use this command, SSH must be installed on your local machine and available from the command line.".

Amazon says I must have ssh-keygen as well as SSH installed but I can't really find where to install SSH onto my computer.

I have installed OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH server through **windows settings** but that doesn't work. Can anyone help?